# Find the cursor targeted element id in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor

In contenteditable div, I have  different child element id. ***At the time of cursor move*** inside the contenteditable tag.  I need get the cursor position element id.

Like this : example

1. if `cursor` position on `one` string get the output is id of cursor position element like
   `1`
2. if is `two` output `2`

I try like this but i don't find cursor target child id. its only on parent.

```js
function check(e){
  console.log($(e.target).attr('id'))
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contentEditable="true"   id="res" tabindex="2"  onkeydown="check(event)">solve:
<span id="1">one</span>
  <p id="2">two</p>
  <i id="3">three</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
$('#res').on('keyup', function() {
  var el = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.parentNode;
  console.log(el.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contentEditable="true" id="res" tabindex="2">solve:
  <span id="1" class='number'>one</span>
  <p id="2" class='number'>two</p>
  <i id="3" class='number'>three</i>
</div>
```

You can read about `window.getSelection()` at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection).

You can read about `window.getSelection()` used in combination with `getRangeAt()` at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection).

Comment: its a mousemove not like that only with keyevent

Comment: can you give some reference link  for that functions

Comment: @prasad, yes I can. Added a link in my updated answer. Hope it helps.